# Cross-domain XML Request 403 Error

Tags: php, jquery, xml, .htaccess

I'm trying to get an RSS feed reader plugin working. Using the code on http://www.script-tutorials.com/importing-multiple-rss-feeds-using-newswidget-jquery/:

```
<div id="newsWidget"> 
    <div class="intro">Below you find some <strong>random</strong> rss feeds from few sources using extended format. Every <strong>15 seconds</strong> the list is updated.</div>
    <ul id="news"></ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.newsWidget.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('ul#news').newswidget({ source: ['http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/us', 'http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/world', 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml'],
        proxyUrl: "get_rss_feed.php",
        limitItems: 10,
        refresh: 15000,
        random: true,
        itemDateElement: "span",
        itemLinkElement: "span",
        itemWebsiteTitleElement: 'span',
        linkTitle: true,
        format: "title,description,date,link,websiteTitle"});
</script>
```

And the PHP (get_rss_feed.php), which is in charge of acting like a proxy to avoid Cross-domain errors is:

```
<?php

$sUrl = $_GET['url'];
header( 'Content-Type: text/xml' );
readfile($sUrl);

?>
```

---

jQuery.newsWidget's code is here: https://code.google.com/p/plosdb/source/browse/trunk/Website/scripts/jquery.newsWidget.js?r=114

---

The problem is that I keep running into 403 Access Forbidden on the feed urls. The newsWidget.js turns the feed urls into: http://example.com/?url=the-other-site.xml in order to avoid CORS restrictions. So I'm wondering if the problem is server-based. Do I need to change my .htaccess or change file permissions for the dynamic url (the '?url=') to work?

I tried other RSS reader scripts and ran into the same 403 error, so advice on creating an RSS reader that is able to pull multiple RSS feeds (across external domains) is very welcome.